# Iron has only 2 valence electrons... How did it became four?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, orbitals

http://youtu.be/bht9AJ1eNYc?t=24m50s at 24:50 said Iron has 4 electrons, Iron has only 2 valence electrons... How did it became four?

Also... Why magnetic field of electrons don't cancel each other out...?

If the  **valence electrons** are 2, 4, 6, etc... (**even numbers**), nothing will remain because half of them will cancel the other half which will lead to **zero magnetic electrons**.

**Valence electrons** with 3, 5, etc... (**odd numbers**), e.g. with 5 magnetic electrons, 4 will cancel each other out, hence only **one** magnectic electron will remain... so do with **7** VE, **1** VE will remain because Six VE cancel each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electronic configuration of iron is: $Ar\,3d^6\,4s^2$. the two electrons in the $4s$ orbital are paired, and two of the electrons in the $3d$ orbitals are paired leaving four unpaired electrons.

In general when you are populating the $p$, $d$, $f$, etc orbitals the electrons will only pair up when they have no choice. So for example in manganese where the configuration is $3d^5$ all five $d$ electrons are unpaired.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that the images that the video provides are mostly wrong, it does not talk about valence electrons; it just says 4 electrons. These are from the $d$-orbital. The magnetic contribution of the 2 electrons in the $s$ orbital is zero, as you correctly note.With respect to why 6 electrons in $d$ result in 4 remaining spins, in contrast to your wrong 2,4,6,..-rule, you should check [Hund's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules).
Eventually, the presence of these extra 4 electrons is by far not sufficient to get ferromagnetism in solid iron. You may get a rough idea by checking the [Stoner criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoner_criterion), but at the end its quantum mechanics, band structures, etc.